# Tafseer of "لَعَلِيٌّ حَکيم / sublime and wise" (Shia view)

Tags: tafseer, shiism, surat-az-zukhruf

In Shi'a view, all the verses of Qur'an have the inner truth represented by an Imam. I think one of those verses is the verse 4 of Zukhruf:

> لوَ إِنَّهُ في‏ أُمِّ الْکِتابِ لَدَيْنا لَعَلِيٌّ حَکيمٌ
>
> And it is with Us, in the Source Book, **sublime and wise**

In this ayah, who is "لَعَلِيٌّ حَکيم / sublime and wise"? Are there any Hadiths that elaborate on this point?

Answer (score 1):

```
               In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

According the verse as you pointed out:

> لوَ إِنَّهُ في‏ أُمِّ الْکِتابِ لَدَيْنا لَعَلِيٌّ حَکيمٌ
>
> And it is with Us, in the Source Book, sublime and wise

I studied to some extent regarding some Shia tafseers, on the whole I inferred some related meanings from it (according to my limited knowledge), which can illustrate the mentioned words as followings:

- Dignified, high-ranking, elevated: for the word لعلی
- Firm and consistent: for the word حکیم

---

On the other hand, (based on some narrations) it is interpreted from the word علی as Imam Ali (a.s.).
Since according to some tafseers: there are two verses that mentions Imam Ali (a.s.) which are as follows:

1. آیة 4 سورة زخرف‌: «وَ إِنَّه‌ُ فِی‌َّ أُم‌ِّ الْکِتَـَب‌ِ لَدَیْنَا
   لَعَلِی‌ُّ حَکِیم‌
   (Surah Zukhruf, verse 4)
2. آیة 50 سورة مریم‌: «وَ جَعَلْنَا لَهُم‌ْ لِسَان‌َ صِدْق‌ٍ عَلِیًّا
   (Surah Maryam, verse 50)

   ---

For more info. about the mentioned matter, you’d better refer to [makarem.ir](http://makarem.ir/main.aspx?typeinfo=1&lid=0&catid=30748&mid=254168)

---

**References:**

- [tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#43:4)
- [makarem.ir](http://makarem.ir/main.aspx?typeinfo=1&lid=0&catid=30748&mid=254168)
- [tadabbor.org](http://tadabbor.org/?page=tadabbor&SOID=43&AYID=4)

Answer (score 0):

According to my translation in Persian (by Seyed MohammadReza Safavi and with the basis of Al-Mizan Tafsir) the subject isn't anyone but it refers only to the Qur'an itself and it's only about the gratest of Qur'an and its concepts.